# Argument type 'Error' does not conform to expected type Swift.Error

Tags: swift, error-handling

Why is passing an error give me `Argument type 'Error' does not conform to expected type 'Swift.Error'`?

```
enum AltError: Error {
    case error(Error), initializesWereNil
}


enum ErrorAlt<Preferred, Error> {
    
    case preferred(Preferred)
    case error(AltError)
    
    init?(_ preferred: Preferred?, _ err: Error?) {
        if let preferred = preferred {
            self = .preferred(preferred)
        } else if let passedError = err {
            self = .error(.error(passedError))
        } else {
            self = .error(.initializesWereNil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the generic type `Error` from the `ErrorAlt` definition:

```
enum ErrorAlt<Preferred> {
    //...
}
```

Comment: enum ErrorAlt<Preferred, Error> {
    
    case preferred(Preferred)
    case error(Error)
    case initializesWereNil
    
    init?(_ preferred: Preferred?, _ err: Error?) {
        if let preferred = preferred {
            self = .preferred(preferred)
        } else if let passedError = err {
            self = .error(passedError)
        } else {
            self = .initializesWereNil
        }
    }
}

Comment: General rule of thumb: Never name your custom types similar to the default types. Rename the `Error` -> `GenericError`.

Comment: enum ErrorAlt<Preferred> {
    
    case preferred(Preferred)
    case error(Error)
    case initializersWereNil
    
    init(_ preferred: Preferred?, _ err: Error?) {
        if let preferred = preferred {
            self = .preferred(preferred)
        } else if let passedError = err {
            self = .error(passedError)
        } else {
            self = .initializersWereNil
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a good idea to not use names that conflict with names declared in other modules.

You can either replace `Error` generic parameter with some other name or explicitly constraint to Swift's `Error` type using the module name:

```swift
enum ErrorAlt<Preferred, Error: Swift.Error>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, what's `Swift.Error`? I understand `Error` is a protocol. But I don't understand the `Swift` part in front of it. What is `Swift.Error`, how is it different than just `Error`?  And what is the "module name"?

Comment: @Andrej `Swift` is the name of the module that contains the `Error` protocol.